# How to Automatically update all devices in device manager

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update, device-manager

In Windows device manager it is possible to "manually" start an automatic update of a device. But its very tedious, each device has to be clicked (as it is not known if that particular device has an update available) - then the popups have to be clicked - and one has to wait for the online search to finish.

So I hoped there is some Powershell script being able to do this, or maybe a registry entry to have "Windows Update" taking care of that.

(Ehm yes, Windows does NOT automatically update ALL devices in device manager).

Comment: @Antz _devcon_ seems perfect, at least the documentation says it can update. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon
Will have to try, thx!

Comment: @Antz I tried _devcon_, as it seems it does not do a online lookup for the drivers. It can only install a given _inf_ file.

Comment: seems like I will have to write a autoit script, something like this: http://www.blueworld.ca/2014/11/autoit-modify-com-port-properties/

Comment: Seems I found a solution, https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/windows-update-minitool.64939/
 original thread: http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=48142#2

still have to verify.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The article
[Script to install or update drivers directly from Microsoft Catalog](http://rzander.azurewebsites.net/script-to-install-or-update-drivers-directly-from-microsoft-catalog/)
contains a PowerShell script for doing what is asked.

The article includes good explanations of each part of the script.
I reproduce below just the bare script with only minor changes (which I have not tested):

```
#search and list all missing Drivers

$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session           
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher() 

$Searcher.ServiceID = '7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d'
$Searcher.SearchScope =  1 # MachineOnly
$Searcher.ServerSelection = 3 # Third Party

$Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and Type='Driver' and ISHidden=0"
Write-Host('Searching Driver-Updates...') -Fore Green  
$SearchResult = $Searcher.Search($Criteria)          
$Updates = $SearchResult.Updates

#Show available Drivers

$Updates | select Title, DriverModel, DriverVerDate, Driverclass, DriverManufacturer | fl

#Download the Drivers from Microsoft

$UpdatesToDownload = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$updates | % { $UpdatesToDownload.Add($_) | out-null }
Write-Host('Downloading Drivers...')  -Fore Green  
$UpdateSession = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.Session
$Downloader = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
$Downloader.Updates = $UpdatesToDownload
$Downloader.Download()

#Check if the Drivers are all downloaded and trigger the Installation

$UpdatesToInstall = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$updates | % { if($_.IsDownloaded) { $UpdatesToInstall.Add($_) | out-null } }

Write-Host('Installing Drivers...')  -Fore Green  
$Installer = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
$Installer.Updates = $UpdatesToInstall
$InstallationResult = $Installer.Install()
if($InstallationResult.RebootRequired) {  
Write-Host('Reboot required! please reboot now..') -Fore Red  
} else { Write-Host('Done..') -Fore Green }
```

---

A general-purpose and powerful package is
[**PSWindowsUpdate**](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc).

Here are a couple of tutorials on installing and using it :

- [Windows 10: Update and Upgrade Windows 10 using PowerShell](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/76207-update-upgrade-windows-10-using-powershell.html).
- [Managing Windows Updates with PowerShell](https://www.petri.com/manage-windows-updates-with-powershell-module)

The package adds the `Get-WUInstall` command (and others) with which you may
get and install updates.
The source of `Get-WUInstall` is also available separately
[from github](https://github.com/joeypiccola/PSWindowsUpdate/blob/master/Get-WUList.ps1).

Another example on its use is found in the article
[PS Script to automate Windows and MS Updates](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2001180-ps-script-to-automate-windows-and-ms-updates).

Comment: Beautiful! I extended the script a bit, 
as title `#set Window Title
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Driver Updater by harrymc"`
and to prevent the powershell from closing 
`Write-Host
Write-Host('Press any key to exit ...') -Fore Yellow  
$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")`
and to run the script from a a batch: 
`@echo off
powershell.exe -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "&{start-process powershell -ArgumentList ' -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -noprofile -file ""%~dp0update.ps1""' -verb RunAs}
`
while the ps script is named update.ps1 and is in same dir.

Comment: It did not work for me (`Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240024`)

Comment: It stops during "Searching driver-updates":

`Exception from HRESULT: 0x80248014  
At line:12 char:1  
+ $SearchResult = $Searcher.Search($Criteria)  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`  

Any ideas?

Comment: @Jonas I had this error on a domain PC with WSUS server configured. To resolve, I added these lines (from the article linked in the answer), to add the Microsoft Catalog as an Update-Source at the top of the script: `$UpdateSvc = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager            
$UpdateSvc.AddService2("7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d",7,"")` and at the bottom, to remove the Catalog again: `$updateSvc.Services | ? { $_.IsDefaultAUService -eq $false -and $_.ServiceID -eq "7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d" } | % { $UpdateSvc.RemoveService($_.ServiceID) }`

Answer (score 3):

An Application **Windows Update MiniTool** exists which can get those drivers, yet its capable of much more - regarding windows updates.

(I personally still prefer the script from harrymc, its painless - just start it and done)

---

- [English Forum](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/windows-update-minitool.64939/)
- [Russian Forum (original source)](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=48142#2)

Quoted from the English Forum:

[image: Screenshot from the application]

```
An alternative to the standard Windows Update
What you can do:

 - Check for updates
 - Download updates
 - Installing Updates
 - Deleting installed updates
 - Hiding unwanted updates
 - Get direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files
 - View update history
 - Configure Automatic Updates
```

Comment: I still use this on W10, it stops auto updates which is the best feature.

Answer (score 2):

Another tool to update, very similar to "Windows Update MiniTool":

https://github.com/DavidXanatos/wumgr

Download link: https://github.com/DavidXanatos/wumgr/releases/latest

[image: Screenshot from the linked tool]

Comment: Looks like a rip off of software I found several years ago (2015), development has stopped and can no longer be found, he was a Russian, his last version was wumt_v30.07.2016>>>>>>>>>>>>>>https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/

Comment: This is not a fork of WUMT. It's written in a different programming language, and WUMT was closed-source so there was nothing to fork anyway. It is "inspired by" WUMT according to the author.