# Automate update hardware drivers in Windows10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, updates

I actually have a fairly simple question, but the answer (I suspect) will not be simple:

In Windows 10 (but also in earlier versions), you can use:

- Configuration Manager
- -> Device Manager
- -> expand tree
- -> right mouse button on element
- -> update driver,
- let Windows search for (for the selected element) most recent driver,
- and (if anything) found, it is installed fully automatically.
- If nothing is found, this is also displayed.

My question is, can this way of searching / installing updates be automated? (I suspect something with Powershell scripts?) And then executed periodically.

Ideal the scripts walks through all elements in the tree so nothing is skipped.

Note: This way of searching for updates often finds updates that are not yet offered within the standard Windows update.

Note: screenshot is in Dutch but pretty clear I guess.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I guess your question has already been answered:
https://superuser.com/questions/1243011/how-to-automatically-update-all-devices-in-device-manager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Automatically update all devices in device manager](https://superuser.com/questions/1243011/how-to-automatically-update-all-devices-in-device-manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 recent versions will update numerous but not all drivers. You can use this.

Name-brand computer vendors provide Driver Update applications which you can run. Some will run automatically and prompt you in a notification to complete the update.

Most drivers (over 80%) require reboot when done so automation needs to be tempered with prompts and user thought.

So you can very much do what you want. The Vendor Update is the best approach for this task at the current time

Comment: If a driver actually does require a reboot it most of the time has bad developers.
I reinstall PCs daily, and will never do a reboot due to driver installation.

Comment: If Windows updates a driver, normally a reboot will follow.

Comment: If Windows updates a driver, and only a driver, then no reboot is needed, feel free to play around with any network driver, uninstall and reinstall. (Windows has a bad habit of telling you reboot required, even if it isn't)

Now some installation programs (which themself should never be needed) forces a reboot, others such as bad graphic drivers might need additional software, and might in that case require replacing locked files. But this as well could be done without reboot if the developers did it right.